# Update URL after model is modified

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a route like this "loans/:loan_id", from a link I redirect to this URL and send an unsaved Loan object as model, so the id is null, which results in the url being "loans/null", however I then save the model and it gets an ID from the server, but how can I update the URL so that it shows the new ID instead of null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a `LoanNewController` or something similar. Then I further assume that you are trying to transition to the new created `loan` object directly after you have created it, this will show an id of null since the create `loan` action is async and you have to wait for the loan to be created on the backend before you do the transition, so in order for it to work you could do the following:

```
App.LoanNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  saveLoan: function() {
    ...
    this.get('store').commit();
  },
  ...
  transitionAfterSave: function() {
    if(this.get('content.id')) {
      this.transitionToRoute('loan', this.get('content'));
    }
  }.observes(content.id)
```

The added observer will observe the `content.id` and when it is set (when the server call has returned) the `transitionAfterSave` will be invoked and the transition will get the content passed to it with the correct id in place.

This answer is based mainly on assumptions, since you didn't reveal that much code, but you get the point I guess.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! but will this create an entry in the browser history? I previously tried transitionTo using loan.one('didCreate') event but then when I pressed back in the browser in would return me to the null URL, which caused some unexpected behavior in the app.